# Google Analytics reporting that Firefox requesting /logo.png as 404 from the root folder

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I have a website receiving unusually high number of Error 404 results, targeting non-existent /logo.png file. It is requested at root (`www.example.com/logo.png`) while it's real location is elsewhere. I noticed those errors in Analytics by looking at Site content/All pages with Page title as primary dimension.

I noticed this in Google Analytics, but couldn't find anything useful in Full referrer/Referral path secondary dimension (it is showing it as (not set)).

Everything I could mine is that it exclusively appears on Firefox/Desktop.

Website is made in WordPress.

Is there any idea what can be the cause for such behavior?

Comment: I'd go through as many pages as you can on your website to see which ones are reproducing the most logo.png errors. If its every page, then chances are a PHP file in your wordpress installation has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the pages that are showing example.com/logo.png instead of where it supposed to be. There is a good chance that the code is showing `<img src="/logo.png" />` when it should be showing `<img src="logo.png" />` . If that is the case, you simply have to fix the html.

An even simpler fix is just to upload the logo.png to your root directory, and then you won't have 404s anymore.